# Add ListFragment to ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to incoporate the Contact List provided in Android Documentation to my View Pager, however I don't understand what's the correct way to do it. Since the Contact List is a ListFragment and not a Fragment I cannot just add it to my ViewPager.

Should I add the contact list to the ViewPager as a ListFragment or should I convert it to a fragment somehow? What's the correct way to add the contact list to my ViewPager?

This is what I am trying:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    // ADD Fragments
    Dialer dialer = new Dialer();
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(dialer);
    ContactListFragment contacts = new ContactListFragment();
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(contacts); // Error:  'addFragment(android.app.fragment) cannot be applied to com.example.android.launcher.ContactListFragment'
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }
}
// ...
```

Contacts ListFragment:

```
public class Contacts extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    //...
```

Comment: ListFragmaent extends Fragments..so whats your problem..can you explain clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using with ViewPager you are most likely to use FragmentPagerAdapter instead of PagerAdapter. You can Extend the FragmentPagerAdapter class and write a method which adds an Fragment to an ArrayList of Fragments. As a ListFragment is just Extended from Fragment Class there should be nothing to worry about.

You can alter you code to this

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
private ViewPager mPager;
private MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // ADD Fragments
    Dialer dialer = new Dialer();
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(dialer);
    Contacts contacts= new Contacts();
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(contacts);

    //set the adapter to the View pager
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return fragments.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment frag) {
        fragments.add(frag);
    }

}
```

This is a rough code so please do excuse me.

Comment: I changed the FragmentPagerStateAdapter to FragmentPagerAdapter but I still have problems adding contacts to the viewPager. I'm getting the error `addFragment(android.app.fragment) cannot be applied to com.example.android.launcher.ContactListFragment` which I was also getting with the FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I corrected a few things that didn't work when I tested it. Let me know if I made a mistake.

Comment: Probably you are extending the Contacts Class from android.app.ListFragment which you should not do in this case so change it to android.support.v4.app.ListFragment. which should work properly.

Comment: also if you are using v4 FragmentPagerAdapter then instead of MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()) do call MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()).

Answer (score 3):

ListFragment extends Fragment, that shouldn't be an issue.

Make sure you are importing `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment` and not `android.app.ListFragment`, though.